# Rails 6 credentials constantly broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

We're running Rails v6.1.4 and the encrypted credentials constantly break and we can't figure out why...

We have four sets of credentials for various environments:

```
config/
  credentials/
    development.key
    development.yml.enc
    ...
```

The *.key files are all `.gitignore`ed. The *.yml.enc are tracked.

There are two developers working on the project. We occasionally update credentials using this command: `rails credentials:edit --environment [ENVIRONMENT]`

We never edit the .key files

But almost every week one of us starts getting...

`Couldn't decrypt config/credentials/development.yml.enc. Perhaps you passed the wrong key?`

...when we try to edit a credentials file.

WHY? What could we doing to cause this? It's incredibly frustrating and I'm ready to give up on this feature because it's wasting so much time.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're not noticing when you introduce merge conflicts into the encrypted file.

Comment: That's an interesting thought but the encrypted files are tracked in Git, so it would be hard not to notice those conflicts, right? Git won't let us merge without resolving conflicts.

Comment: Correct, but I can't speak for your teammates or your own diligence in such things.  A conflict would definitely cause the issue you're reporting, and it's the most likely cause I can imagine.